# How to send a notification email at 1 pm and 6 pm?

Tags: triggers, google-app-maker

I know how to send an email to someone but I do not know how to send it at a certain time.

Can you help me ?

// My code is (scriptClient) :

```
function sendEmailClient(){
  var user = app.pages.pageEmprunt.descendants.TextBox2.value;

  google.script.run

  .withSuccessHandler(function(){
  })
  .withFailureHandler(function(err){
    console.error('erreur');
  })
  .sendEmail(user);
}
```

// And in scriptServer is:

```
function sendEmail(user){

  var htmlBody = 
      "Bonjour!<br/><p>Vous avez emprunter une ou plusieurs clé(s).<br/>"+
       "<b>N'oubliez pas de la ou les ramener et de signer le registre.</b><br/></p>"+
       'Merci';

  var emailObj = {
    to : user,
    subject :  'Remise des clés',
    htmlBody : htmlBody,
    noReplay: true
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailObj);

}
```

Comment: You will want to check out this documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers and then also check out this App Maker sample how to implement it in AM https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/triggers/.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the users to whom the emails should be sent on a database and then get the users from the database using another function and keep looping over sendEmail(user) and inject each user as a parameter. Lets call this function as fetchAndSendEmails(). Now create a trigger which calls this function at 1pm and 6pm everyday like below. All of this should be written in server script.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("fetchAndSendEmails").timeBased().atHour(13).create();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("fetchAndSendEmails").timeBased().atHour(18).create();
```